# Replace sensitive data in VCR gem cassettes request body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vcr

I am able to remove sensitive headers using `filter_sensitive_data` but it does not seem to be working for replacing sensitive data in the request body.

**VCR configuration**

```
VCR.configure do |config|
  config.cassette_library_dir = 'spec/vcr'
  config.hook_into :webmock
  config.configure_rspec_metadata!
  # this does not work for request body
  config.filter_sensitive_data('<PASSWORD-REDACTED>') do
    ENV['PASSWORD']
  end
  # this works for headers
  config.filter_sensitive_data('<Authorization-REDACTED>') do |interaction|
    interaction.request.headers['Authorization'].try(:first)
  end
end
```

**Run spec**

```
PASSWORD=secret bin/rspec spec/my_spec.rb
```

**Cassette**

Recording contains `password=secret` in the request body

but should be `password=PASSWORD-REDACTED`

```
---
http_interactions:
- request:
    method: post
    uri: https://xxxx
    body:
      encoding: US-ASCII
      string: username=somebody%40example.com&password=secret
    headers:
      Accept:
      - application/json
      Content-Type:
      - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      User-Agent:
      - Faraday v2.2.0
      Accept-Encoding:
      - gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3
  response:
    status:
      code: 200
      message: OK
    headers:
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It works well for me. You might need to check the values returned by the **filter_sensitive_data** block as indicated here https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/1-10-1/docs/configuration/filter-sensitive-data

> A substitution string. This is the string that will be written to the cassette file as a placeholder. It should be unique and you may want to wrap it in special characters like { } or < >.

Make sure the string returned by the block are unique.

In your case, I would inspect the value of **ENV['PASSWORD']** and
**interaction.request.headers['Authorization'].try(:first)** if they are correctly returned.